# Tweak Flash videos aspect ratio

Tags: gratis, video, web-browser, flash

I need to use a browser add-on or any other software that can modify the aspect ratio of Flash videos. I would like it to be Linux compatible, but I'm interested in Windows software too.

Here is the problem:

[image]

In this screenshot you can see better that the image is distorted:

[image]

The video should be at 4:3 and it is distorted at 16:9. The same in full screen.

There is no possibility to view the video stream in other player because it is a PPV service available at a specific ISP (that's why I provided no link to that site).

On the [Romanian Television](http://tvrplus.ro) site this feature is provided by the player (you manually choose the aspect ratio):

[image]

[image]

Is there any freeware browser extension or standalone program that can do that?

Answer (score 1):

My first instinct was just to simply say use [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/index.html) this can defiantly play direct from a URL and can correct aspect ratios with no problem.

There is also [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/169622/how-to-play-embedded-flash-videos-in-external-players) on AskUbuntu that gives more suggestions and details for alternative video players.

Comment: VLC or other players work in most cases, but not here.

Comment: If the reason that VLC doesn't work is password/sign-in  needed then maybe adding VLC as the player in your web browser settings.